# facebook share button script not loading on https because of certificate error

Tags: facebook, https

I am running my site on `https`. I have added some social sharing buttons on my site like `LinkedIn`, `Twitter` and `Facebook`.

everything is working perfectly all right but the javascript file of facebook share button is not being loaded on `https`.

Following is the url which is being blocked by browsers becuase of certificate error.

```
https://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share
```

Here is the snapshot of the page I see when I hit the above url directly in the browser.

[image: Facebook share script certificate error]

Why there is a certificate error on `Facebook`?

is there any solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fb.Share is deprecated.  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

Please try using a supported function and see if it also gives you the same issues.

Answer (score 0):

Look i don't know if this is allowable but if you proceed this way, i think it will work:

THe FB.share is a standard file obtained from the CDN from facebook, so it will not change. Therefore, hosts it yourself,

perform a wget, since the certificate is not valid, in linux, do it like this

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share
```

Now, where you need to add the FB.share, do it like this

```
<a name="fb_share" share_url="link to share"</a>
 <script src="FB.Share" type="text/javascript">
 </script>
```